# SQL trigger multi-part identifier error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a trigger that will make the salary of the employees bigger if they have any rents or sales made...

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryCurrentSalary
ON EmployeesSalary
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE EmployeesSalary
SET CurrentSalary=CurrentSalary+((MonthlySalesMade+MonthlyRentsMade)*200)
WHERE EmployeeID =inserted.EmployeeID;
END
```

but I am getting a strange error

The multi-part identifier "inserted.EmployeeID" could not be bound.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Error is right. where is inserted?

Comment: I don't actually understand the meaning of the error

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) and any of the examples? Or did you just write the trigger the way you think the syntax might work? (Hint: You might notice that in the examples `inserted` is in the `FROM`/`JOIN` clauses. In your attempt, `inserted` isn't a table your `UPDATE` statement mentions - you just add it to the `WHERE` clause out of nowhere. Try with simple examples first, don't just write it like you think you already know it...)

Comment: Should this be an after insert trigger, or an after update trigger? Should it be a trigger at all? Seems like this should be a trigger on a sales table somewhere, not on the salary table. You're not inserting a row into the salary table every time an employee makes a sale, I expect.

Comment: Yes, of course i'm not inserting everytime... It's inserted by an other trigger... It's an after insert trigger, and i personally think i'm in the right way but kindda confused if a trigger can react with other triggers

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the `inserted` "view" in a `FROM` clause before you can use it.  One method simply uses `IN`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryCurrentSalary ON EmployeesSalary
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE EmployeesSalary
        SET CurrentSalary = CurrentSalary + ((MonthlySalesMade + MonthlyRentsMade) * 200)
    WHERE EmployeeID IN (SELECT i.EmployeeID FROM inserted i);
END;
```

Comment: your code seems to work but... since my table update is based on 2 other triggers from other tables it doesn't work... is there any way to make this trigger work when some other trigger from the other tables  is activated?

Comment: Example: this is my table     `CREATE TABLE EmployeesSalary
(
EmployeeID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CurrentSalary MONEY DEFAULT 0,-- на процент
MonthlySalesMade INT DEFAULT 0,
MonthlyRentsMade INT DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeesSalary_Employees FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID)
REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeID),
CONSTRAINT CHK_EmployeesSalary CHECK (CurrentSalary>=0 AND MonthlySalesMade>=0 AND MonthlyRentsMade>=0)
);
` and i want it's trigger to be activated when MonthlyRentsMade or MonthlySalesMade is updated (but they are updated by triggers from other tables)

Comment: @MitkoZ What does "doesn't work" mean? Please add information - about your table structure, other triggers, and exactly what happens - to your question. Comments are a terrible place for code.

Comment: yea i see about the comment updates... well the trigger is "made" but it should be something like a nested trigger i don't know if this term even exists

Answer (score 0):

You have to SET NOCOUNT ON and use Inserted in a FROM:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryCurrentSalary
ON EmployeesSalary
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON -- new code
UPDATE EmployeesSalary
SET CurrentSalary=CurrentSalary+((MonthlySalesMade+MonthlyRentsMade)*200)
WHERE EmployeeID IN (Select inserted.EmployeeID from inserted);
END
```

It sounds as if you might not have allowed nested triggers:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'nested triggers', 1 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Comment: Is EmployeeID in the table EmployeeSalary?

Comment: Do you have multiple triggers on the same table?

Comment: Not exactly on it but on other tables still they make the update to this table

Comment: Comment everything out and just leave this code inside:
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT * INTO TESTTABLE FROM INSERTED
Then try running it again. Check the created table TESTTABLE to see the inserted data.

Comment: Test the trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER tr_EmployeesSalaryCurrentSalary
ON EmployeesSalary
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT * INTO TESTTABLE FROM INSERTED
END

Comment: Gordon Linoff method works but... since the columns of the table that should be used when updated (MonthlyMadeSales and MonthlyMadeRents) are based on triggers from other tables ... i think that's the problem

Comment: I added code to my answer to allow nested triggers. Please can you try it. Just run in query window.

Comment: yes i tried it but i get this error "Invalid object name 'INSERTED'.
"

Comment: This is why I rarely come to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'nested triggers' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

Comment: Ok i executed the code... but still my trigger doesn't react to the other triggers

Comment: Ah.. My code turned nested triggers off (0). Can you run my now edited code to turn it back on (1). Sorry. But this means that your original code was kicking off the trigger. Nested trigger settings were not your problem.